# does scrambling increse the bandwidth

Tags: digital-communications

In LTE systems the in the scrambling section, a gold sequence is used. But I've studied that gold sequences are used in spread spectrum communication. This generally increases the bandwidth. So doesn't this mean that scrambling results in an increase of bandwidth.?

regards,
phani tej

Answer (score 1):

No, scrambling does not increase the bandwidth.  Scrambling does even out the bandwidth, such that the power is spread evenly over the signal bandwidth.

You are thinking of chipping, which is used in [DSSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum) systems.  Scrambling and chipping are different processes.

Comment: but both are used to randomize the data. and in the LTE system gold sequence generation is there in the uplink. Does chipping does anything other than randomizing ?

Comment: Chipping is a spread spectrum technique, which, as the term suggests, expands the bandwidth of a signal. Scrambling simply maps a stream of modulating symbols to a new stream, at the same symbol rate. Since there is no change in channel symbol rate, no bandwidth expansion occurs.